# Caliburn's Screen can not be inherited by Window or UserControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I discovered that Window or UserControl can not inherit Caliburn's Screen base class. Am I forced to implement IScreen interface to every window/user control in my WPF application?

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro
Namespace Views
  Public Class CustomView
    Inherits Screen
  End Class
End Namespace
```

> Base class 'Screen' specified for class 'CustomView' cannot be
>   different from the base class 'UserControl' of one of its other
>   partial types.

Comment: I've inherited Screen on WIndow and UserControl before. Why do you say you cannot? Can you show code?

Comment: Those are meant to be used on view models. Why are you trying to do that in the first place? This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: (I)Screen is meant to be in Views. (I)ViewAware is meant to be used in ViewModels to control views to some degree, IMHO.

Comment: Your understanding of the use of those types is incorrect. Review the documentation for the framework  Reference [Caliburn.Micro Documentation: Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn's `Screen` base class is meant to be used on view models.

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro
Namespace ViewModels
  Public Class CustomViewModel
    Inherits Screen

    '...'

  End Class
End Namespace
```

And then used to bind derived view models to the views

```
Imports ViewModels
Namespace Views
  Public Class CustomView
    Inherits Window

    Public Sub New()
        '...'

        Dim viewModel As New CustomViewModel()
        DataContext = viewModel
    End Sub

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Reference [Caliburn.Micro Documentation: Screens, Conductors and Composition](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition)

Comment: Why are you inheriting class from Window and not use Window class directly? Also you are not using anything Caliburn in that view.

Comment: So nothing is needed to be Caliburned on view side, except some XAML stuff like cal:Message?

Comment: @Ondřej that is correct. The project site has some easy to understand documentation one can follow to better understand the framework https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/